# The Complexity of Properly Learning Decision Trees

Tags: decision-trees, pac-learning

Where does [this paper](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-vitaly/ABFKP_Proper_Hardness_08.pdf) prove the middle bullet point of its abstract?

I have looked through that paper fairly thoroughly.

There are three things I want to read how they're getting around.

- Reductions from NP problems to SAT may have the effect

  of applying arbitrarily large polynomials to the input size.
- Theorems 2 and 3 and 20 restrict the runtime of their learning algorithms.
- Theorems 2 and 3 and 20 consider randomized algorithms.